# how to efficiently filter a numpy array so that it contains rows contained in a second array

Tags: numpy, filter, compare

eg. In reality, **a** has 100s thousands of rows. **b** is a fixed size.

```
a = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

b = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

**Im doing this:**

```
matches=[]
for n, a_row in enumerate(a):
    for b_row in b:
        if np.all(a_row ==b_row ):
            matches.append(n)

a[matches]
```

It seems there should be a better way ...

Comment: Are the inputs always zeros and ones? What is the limit on the width?

Comment: the width is the same of both arrays, and the inputs are always ones and zeros.

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the width? For example, is it always less than 64?

Comment: array_b is made by finding the unique rows in array_a. So they are identical in width.

Comment: I get that. Is there an upper bound on the width? Width  = number of columns.

Comment: Perhaps not clear. These are not binary numbers. It is the outcome of a binary classification. what I am trying to accomplish is a boolean mask. So for example in a, the first entry is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. This is present in b, so this should be positive.

Comment: You are misunderstanding my question. Is there a maximum to the number of columns you will be dealing with?

Comment: Sorry :(. This is a sample of the data, so 5 columns. The columns are a fixed number. The rows can be up to 1 million though.

Comment: Right. What is the upper bound on that fixed number? Is it guaranteed to be 64 or less?

Comment: I think I see the confusion... My bad. Array_b is a fixed 5 column, 8 row. Array_a has 5 columns but many rows.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to make sure that I didn't post an answer assuming it could fit into 64 columns and then not work with your real data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.packbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) very effectively here. It will convert any array with eight or fewer columns into a single column of `uint8`:

```
ai = np.packbits(a, axis=-1)
bi = np.packbits(a, axis=-1)
```

For any number of columns up to 64, you can use the appropriate integer type using [`np.min_scalar_type`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.min_scalar_type.html):

```
t = np.min_scalar_type(2**a.shape[-1] - 1)
ai = np.concatenate((ai, np.zeros((a.shape[0], t.itemsize % ai.shape[-1]), np.uint8)), axis=-1)
bi = np.concatenate((bi, np.zeros((a.shape[0], t.itemsize % bi.shape[-1]), np.uint8)), axis=-1)
ai = ai.view(t)
bi = bi.view(t)
```

You can compare the arrays simply with [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) (or [`np.in1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)):

```
mask = np.isin(ai, bi).ravel()
```

You can now index `a` directly as before:

```
a[mask, :]
```

Your original example becomes a one-liner:

```
a[np.in1d(np.packbits(a, axis=-1), np.packbits(b, axis=-1))]
```

For sufficiently large `a`, you may want to speed things up further with a sort or `set`-based approach.